# ThreadPoolExecutor execute tasks in queue first after creating new threads when queue capacity is reached instead of executing the new incoming jobs

Tags: java, queue, threadpoolexecutor

I have written a simple demo to mimic demonstrate the problem I am facing.

```
public abstract class ThreadPoolTest {

    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
    private static final int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 15;
    private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAX_POOL_SIZE, 1l, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
        execueInBatch(pool, 25);
        pool.shutdown();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    private static void execueInBatch(ThreadPoolExecutor pool, int num) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            final Integer it = Integer.valueOf(i);
            try {
                System.out.println("About to start " + i);
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Started- " + it);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000l);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Completed- " + it);
                }, pool);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " for-" + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response is below:
About to start 1
About to start 2
About to start 3
Started- 1
About to start 4
Started- 2
About to start 5
Started- 3
About to start 6
About to start 7
About to start 8
About to start 9
Started- 4
About to start 10
About to start 11
About to start 12
About to start 13
About to start 14
About to start 15
About to start 16
About to start 17
Started- 5
About to start 18
About to start 19
About to start 20
About to start 21
About to start 22
About to start 23
Started- 21
Started- 22
Started- 23
About to start 24
About to start 25
Started- 24
Started- 25
Completed- 1
Started- 6
Completed- 3
Completed- 2
Completed- 4
Started- 8
Started- 7
Started- 9
Completed- 5
Started- 10
Completed- 23
Completed- 21
Started- 11
Completed- 22
Started- 12
Started- 13
Completed- 25
Completed- 24
Started- 14
Started- 15
Completed- 6
Started- 16
Completed- 8
Completed- 9
Started- 17
Completed- 7
Started- 18
Started- 19
Completed- 10
Started- 20
Completed- 13
Completed- 11
Completed- 12
Completed- 15
Completed- 14
Completed- 16
Completed- 17
Completed- 18
Completed- 19
Completed- 20

What I need is to start task 6 before starting task 21.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: When N threads pick up a queued item around the same time you can't tell which will actually begin first unless N=1 thread or you have add logic at start of each step to wait until specific counter event happens (so 2 won't continue unless event 1 was started).

Answer (score 1):

When there are many threads in the pool you have no guarantee which one will actually enter the runnable task first unless the pool size is one - and nothing runs at same time - or if you add additional barrier / check inside each task to guarantee your specific sequential starting order within parallel execution.

This example shows using `CountDownLatch` for every integer. Each task checks for the `CountDownLatch` of previous integer having been triggered before counting down it's own latch and then continues with that task item.

```
private static void execueInBatch(ThreadPoolExecutor pool, int num) throws InterruptedException {

    CountDownLatch prev = new CountDownLatch(0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        final Integer it = Integer.valueOf(i);
        final CountDownLatch thislatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch prevlatch = prev;
        try {
            System.out.println("About to start " + i+" in "+Thread.currentThread());
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    // This check is not needed, it just shows how often threads are running out of the add sequence:
                    if(!prevlatch.await(1, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
                        System.out.println("Note: out of sequence run - " + it+ " in "+Thread.currentThread());

                    // Await event start of previous value of "it" to guarantee sequential start
                    prevlatch.await();

                    System.out.println("Started- " + it+ " in "+Thread.currentThread());

                    // Count down as this one is starting
                    thislatch.countDown();

                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Completed- " + it+ " in "+Thread.currentThread());
            }, pool);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " for-" + i+ " in "+Thread.currentThread());
        }
        prev = thislatch;
    }
}
```

This isn't an ideal solution as it will clog up certain pool threads whenever an out of order value is processed first (such as item 21 as you observed), and those later value threads will be waiting for earlier actions on other threads to end, and then for other pool threads to pick up the items in-between.

Comment: Note that even with the above latch to ensure entry to each task is in sequence, there is no guarantee that the very next line of each task will run in the order defined when there is more than one thread in the pool.